# Converting YUV420P to RGBA using OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, yuv

I am working on processing video using OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android. The picture data is being pulled as YUV420P and I need to process them in RGBA in my OpenGL fragment shader somehow.

How do I convert the YUV420P data into RGBA? (Performance is key given it's video)

UPDATE: Got further thanks to Brad Larsson's answer but it doesn't look right.

UPDATE2: Duh, I was still using my RGBA fragment shader. Of course it looked wrong. Now I have another issue though. Let me dig further.

UPDATE3: OK, something is not going right here.

[image]

I am using this for the textures. Is this correct?

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, width, height, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, luminanceBuffer);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, width / 2, height / 2, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, chrominanceBuffer);
```

UPDATE4: Using `GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA` sorted the interlacing problem but the picture is still corrupted BUT... I just learned that the problem lies in my byte buffer so marking this one as answered.

Comment: If you use ``GL_LUMINANCE`` both red and green channel contain same value. You should somehow make ``GL_RG`` possible if you want to follow Brad's answer. I'm not exactly sure what ``GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA`` does but it might contain separate values for red/green/blue (these are same) and alpha.

Comment: Tried a few different combinations but couldn't get it to work unless it's GL_LUMINANCE. On the screenshot above, it looks like the upper part half has the luminance levels of the lower part of the original video frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple has a couple of examples for iOS where they convert from YUV420 planar data to RGBA in an OpenGL ES 2.0 shader. While not specifically for Android, you should still be able to use this GLSL shader code to accomplish what you want.

This is what I use in a conversion fragment shader based on their example:

```
 varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;

 uniform sampler2D luminanceTexture;
 uniform sampler2D chrominanceTexture;

 void main()
 {
     mediump vec3 yuv;
     lowp vec3 rgb;

     yuv.x = texture2D(luminanceTexture, textureCoordinate).r;
     yuv.yz = texture2D(chrominanceTexture, textureCoordinate).rg - vec2(0.5, 0.5);

     // BT.601, which is the standard for SDTV is provided as a reference
     /*
      rgb = mat3(      1,       1,       1,
      0, -.39465, 2.03211,
      1.13983, -.58060,       0) * yuv;
      */

     // Using BT.709 which is the standard for HDTV
     rgb = mat3(      1,       1,       1,
                0, -.21482, 2.12798,
                1.28033, -.38059,       0) * yuv;

     gl_FragColor = vec4(rgb, 1);
 }
```

`luminanceTexture` is the Y plane of your image as a texture, and `chrominanceTexture` is the UV plane.

I believe the above is tuned for video range YUV, so you may need to adjust these values for full range YUV. This shader runs in a fraction of a millisecond for 1080p video frames on an iPhone 4S.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Will try this. How do I upload the two uniforms? I assume I upload the luminance buffer as GL_LUMINANCE but what should the smaller chrominance buffer use? Also GL_LUMINANCE I take it?

Comment: I updated my question with what it looks like now. Something is going a bit wrong.

Comment: @BlueVoodoo - GL_LUMINANCE should be fine for the luminance plane (A5 iOS devices have a nice GL_RED_EXT one-component format that's ideal for this). You're going to need more than one component for the chrominance texture, though, because you have UV components interlaced in there. GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA might be the way to go here (again, A5 iOS devices have GL_RG_EXT as a great type for this). See the example here (iOS, but still mostly applicable) for more: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6510542/19679

Comment: Why would one choose the apple 1 and 2 component extensions over the standard versions?

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks, I still have issues. I wonder if the issue is in my buffer. Seen anything like it before? (See my update)

Comment: My poblem lies in my buffer. Managed to get the luminance to display properly by modifying it. Marking this as an answer.

Comment: @RhythmicFistman - Because they allow for true one-component or two-component internal formats for these textures, instead of textures that are internally RGBA and just mapped to luminance or luminance and alpha. This makes the textures take up significantly less memory, potentially be faster to access (greater cache hits), and allows them to be used for direct memory mapping via the texture caches when uploading YUV frames from the iOS camera.

Comment: @brad are you sure? luma/luma_alpha work fine with texture caches on A4/A5 and are not converted to RGBA internally. The only difference I've observed between the apple extensions is the texel layout... Am I missing something?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman - At WWDC 2011, they indicated that the texture caches needed these extensions in order to work with Y and UV data. I never tried, since I took them at their word. Similarly, the Khronos description for EXT_texture_rg: http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_texture_rg.txt seemed to indicate that the luminance component was replicated across four color channels, but Table 3.8 from the OpenGL ES 2.0 specification does state that luminance and alpha are the only two components in those internal formats. I need to explore this.

Comment: @RhythmicFistman - I just tested this out, and you're right, GL_LUMINANCE and GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA works just fine with the texture caches. The only difference between this and GL_RED_EXT seems to be the way components are handled in fragment shaders. Performance is identical when either is used for YUV sources on A5 devices. Now I'm really curious as to what problem this extension solves, because the engineers made it sound like this was necessary for fast YUV data handling from the camera.

Comment: @brad thanks for double checking. I forgot to ask what the extensions were actually good for at WWDC 2012 and it's been gnawing at me ever since. Maybe we should take this epic comment thread to the devforum.

Comment: @RhythmicFistman - In case you're still curious, I did find one significant difference, and that's the fact that you can't render to an FBO with a GL_LUMINANCE or GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA texture attached, but can render to a GL_RED_EXT or GL_RG_EXT one. Doesn't change anything for the input sources we're talking about here, but that does explain where they could be useful.

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks! That's been bothering me for ages. I've been meaning to try a rgb to yuv shader and you've saved me a lot of bother.

Comment: whats the rational for decrementing 0.5 from U,V values?

Comment: @sramij - If I remember correctly, it's because the values range from 128-255, either because of video range YUV being used or because of only half a byte being used for each. Can't remember which it was.

Comment: @BradLarson - maybe indeed the chroma 128-255. I see now; it's just converting U into (U-128) and V into (V-128) to to convert those into RGB values later by a matrix complication. if it wasn't to convert into RGB but simply manipulate YUV, i think i wouldn't have to do that. right?

Comment: Just an FYI, but subtracting 0.5 is not quite right as the incoming float values are in terms of 1.0/255.0 steps. One should use 128.0/255.0 instead so that grayscale values land exactly on zero.