# Draw YUV image using GLKit openGL - iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, rendering, glkit

I want to render a yuv image on an iOS device. I presume it can be achieved using openGL. (Actually I have to render multiple such images in succession)

What I understand is that GLKit is an abstraction that iOS created, in which there is a `GLKView` which will have and handle the render buffer. I am currently trying to use a `GLKViewController` and frame update is being done successfully with desired fps. This I conform by using `glClear` function call.

Now the task is to render an image on the view.

There is a class `GLKBaseEffect` which will have basic shaders. I can't figure out what properties to set, so I just create it and call `prepareToDraw` before each render.

There is a class for handling textures, `GLKTextureLoader`, but it appears to me that it only works with Quartz images, i.e., yuv420 planar can't be loaded into the texture using this class.

```
// create the texture
GLuint texture;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8,  width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, [imageNSData bytes]);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);
```

I use this code for generating a texture and binding it, but I don't really know what I am trying to do here. And whatever it is, it doesn't bring up any image on screen, and I don't know what to do next.

I have not created any shaders, assuming baseEffect will have something.

And this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH103-SW8 tells me that I'll have to use EAGLayer to render images on screen.

Can I use GLKit to render images? If YES, do we have any sample code or tutorial that wouldn't use `GLKTextureLoader` class (I couldn't find any)? If NO, is there a similar tutorial for render using `EAGLLayer` (I have not explored about it till now) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're really asking about a few different topics here:

- How to draw with `GLKView` vs `CAEAGLLayer`
- How `GLKBaseEffect` and `GLKTextureLoader` fit into OpenGL ES drawing in general
- How to draw a texture once you have one
- How to render YUV image data

I'll try to address each in turn...

---

`GLKView` is just fine for any OpenGL ES drawing you want to do -- it does everything that the older documentation you linked to does (setting up framebuffers, `CAEAGLLayer`s, etc) for you so you don't have to write that code. Inside the `GLKView` drawing method (`drawRect:` or `glkView:drawInRect:`, depending on whether you're drawing in a subclass or delegate), you write the same OpenGL ES drawing code you would for `CAEAGLLayer` (or any other system).

---

You can use `GLKView`, `GLKTextureLoader`, and `GLKBaseEffect` independently of each other. If you want to write all your own drawing code and use your own shaders, you can draw in a `GLKView` without using `GLKBaseEffect`. (You can even mix and match `GLKBaseEffect` and your own stuff, like you see when you create a new Xcode project with the OpenGL Game template.) Likewise, `GLKTextureLoader` loads image data and spits out the `name` you'll need for binding it for drawing, and you can use that regardless of whether you're drawing it with `GLKBaseEffect`.

---

Once you get a texture, whether via `GLKTextureLoader` or reading/decoding the data yourself and providing it to `glTexImage2D`, there are three basic steps to drawing with it:

1. Bind the texture name with `glBindTexture`.
2. Draw some geometry to be textured (using `glDrawArrays`, `glDrawElements`, or similar)
3. Have a fragment shader that looks up texels and outputs colors.

If you just want to draw an image that fills your view, just draw a quad (two triangles). Here's the code I use to set up a vertex array object with one quad when I want to draw fullscreen:

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) {
    GLKVector3 position;
    GLKVector2 texcoord;
} Vertex;

static Vertex vertexData[] = {
    {{-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f}, {0.0f,  0.0f}},
    {{-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f}, {0.0f,  1.0f}},
    {{ 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f}, {1.0f,  0.0f}},
    {{ 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f}, {1.0f,  1.0f}},
};

glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray);
glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexData), vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid *)offsetof(Vertex, position));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid *)offsetof(Vertex, texcoord));
glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
```

Then, to draw it:

```
glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

That's just the geometry-drawing part. Combine this with a `GLKBaseEffect` -- whose `transform` property is the default identity transform, and whose `texture2d0` property is set up with the `name` of a texture you've loaded via `GLKTextureLoader` or other means -- and you'll get a view-filling billboard with your texture on it.

---

Finally, the YUV part... for which I'll mostly punt. Where are you getting your YUV texture data? If it's from the device camera, you should look into `CVOpenGLESTexture`/`CVOpenGLESTextureCache`, as covered by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9574798/957768). Regardless, you should be able to handle YUV textures using the `APPLE_rgb_422` extension, as covered by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6510542/957768). You can also look into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8653891/957768) for some help writing fragment shaders to process YUV to RGB on the fly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is a great help. About the yuv part, do we really have to convert it to rgb data before sending it for rendering? Isn't there a method using which we can just pass the yuv buffer to openGL framework, and it handles the conversion itself?
And what I get is, that I'll have to create a rectangle using vertex shader first, and then the image will be rendered in that area, am I correct?

Comment: All pixel data needs to be RGB eventually -- the screen is an RGB device! As far as I'm aware, there's no way to get the YUV to RGB conversion done for you in an OpenGL texture, but your fragment shader can do the conversion at the last possible moment, as seen in the [`GLCameraRipple`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GLCameraRipple/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code.

Comment: yeah. That's what I just downloaded. I think I'll figure out the approach now, thanks for the help.